# CSS Line Dividor

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to organize two sets of information in a particular way. I have a very crude mock-up here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fROSh.jpg

I have everything working except for the diving line between the two sets of info. I've tried setting up the entire thing as a table and then setting the appropriate border styles, but that didn't work out so well.

Here's what I currently have that gets me everything except the middle dividing line:

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; table-layout: fixed">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="left_image" class="images" alt="left_image" height="auto" width="300" style="border: 2px solid #5b5b5b">
        </td>
        <td style="display:block;">
            <div style="float: left; margin: 20px 0 0 20px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">Name:</td><td><span id="left_name" style="font-weight: bold"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">Category:</td>
                        <td><span id="left_category" style="font-weight: bold"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">ID:</td>
                        <td><span id="left_id" style="font-weight: bold;"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <div style="float: right; margin: 100px 20px 0 0;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">Name:</td>
                        <td><span id="right_name" style="font-weight: bold"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">Category:</td>
                        <td><span id="right_category" style="font-weight: bold"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75px;">ID:</td>
                        <td><span id="right_id" style="font-weight: bold"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="right_image" class="images" alt="right_image" height="auto" width="300" style="border: 2px solid #5b5b5b">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn4 btn4-confirm" onclick="selectLeftID()">Select Left</button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn4 btn4-confirm" onclick="electRightID()">Select Right</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is just experimental code, it hasn't been cleaned up yet, so please ignore all the in-line styling.

Here's a sloppy example I threw together: https://jsfiddle.net/33pc23w0/2/

I would like to make the line in code and not use any images since I'd like the elements to be flexible in size. Any suggestions on the middle lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. I set the main container to `relative` position and added two `absolute` position `divs` with appropriate borders and dimensions to handle the dividers.

```css
.main-container {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.divider-top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
}

.divider-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 167px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 300px;
  border: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

.details_images {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn4 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.btn4.focus,
.btn4:focus,
.btn4:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn4-confirm {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #4cae4c;
}

.btn4-confirm:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #449d44;
  border-color: #398439;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="divider-top"></div>
  <div class="divider-bottom"></div>

  <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; table-layout: fixed">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img id="left_image" class="images" alt="left_image" height="auto" width="200" src="https://catalogue.millsarchive.org/images/generic-icons/blank.png" style="border: 2px solid #5b5b5b">
      </td>
      <td style="display:block;">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 20px 0 0 20px;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">Name:</td>
              <td><span id="left_name" style="font-weight: bold">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">Category:</td>
              <td><span id="left_category" style="font-weight: bold">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">ID:</td>
              <td><span id="left_id" style="font-weight: bold;">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; margin: 100px 20px 0 0;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">Name:</td>
              <td><span id="right_name" style="font-weight: bold">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">Category:</td>
              <td><span id="right_category" style="font-weight: bold">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 75px;">ID:</td>
              <td><span id="right_id" style="font-weight: bold">Blah</span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
      <td>
        <img id="right_image" class="images" alt="right_image" height="auto" width="200" src="https://catalogue.millsarchive.org/images/generic-icons/blank.png" style="border: 2px solid #5b5b5b">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn4 btn4-confirm" onclick="selectLeftID()">Select Left</button>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn4 btn4-confirm" onclick="electRightID()">Select Right</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great! I'll try to implement this tomorrow.